# Replace a specific line in a batch file with the content of a text file?

Tags: batch-file, text, replace, types

Is there a way I can use the type command to replace a specific line in a batch file with the content of a text file?

For example, let's say I have a batch like this:

```
@echo off
echo hello world
::replace
pause>nul
exit
```

And I want to replace the `::replace` line with the content of a text file for example:

```
echo this
echo was
echo replaced
```

Is that possible? if not is there another way i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example replaces the line if it matches `::replace` exactly, not contains. The first example replaces the line in the main script itself:

```
@echo off
set "infile=%~0"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%infile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>%infile%') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:*]=!"
    if "!line!" == "::replace" (
       set line=
       type replace_file.txt
    )>>!infile!
    echo(!line!>>!infile!
    endlocal
 )

rem sample replace section here.
@echo off
echo hello world
::replace
pause>nul
```

to have it replace the lines in another batch file, then add the name of the file where it says "ADD FILE NAME HERE":

```
@echo off
set "infile=ADD FILE NAME HERE"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%infile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>%infile%') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:*]=!"
    if "!line!" == "::replace" (
       set line=
       type replace_file.txt
    )>>!infile!
    echo(!line!>>!infile!
    endlocal
 )
```

a word of caution though, this is replacing the script itself by `break`ing the original and re-creating it while replacing what you ask it to. If you make a mistake and break the code, it will break your script, so always make a copy of the script/s you want to replace code in. you can do that automatically by adding a line in the script to copy the file before the for loop. Something like:

```
copy "%infile%" "%infile%.bck"
```

Comment: Oh and just so you know, your search/replacement string cannot contain any exclamation marks `!` if you have a line with one, then you cannot use delayed expansion.